# How to link c files and header files correctly in CMakeList in ROS2?

Tags: c, cmake, linker, ros2, colcon

I am new to ROS2 and do not have any prior knowledge of Cmake.

I have a ROS2 package that looks like this:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── package_name
│       ├── bmi088.h
│       ├── bmi08x_defs.h
│       ├── bmi08x.h
│       ├── rpi_bmi088.h
│       └── rpi_i2c.h
├── package.xml
├── scripts
├── src
│   ├── bmi088.c
│   ├── imu_data_reader.cpp
│   ├── rpi_bmi088.c
│   └── rpi_i2c.c
└── package_name
    └── __init__.py
```

I got the sensor drivers from a github repo and tested the code by running the makefile that was included in the repo. The code worked perfectly, but when implementing in ROS2, I got the following error when building with colcon:

```
Starting >>> package_name
--- stderr: package_name                                                               
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/imu_data_reader.dir/src/imu_data_reader.cpp.o: in function `main':
imu_data_reader.cpp:(.text+0x12a): undefined reference to `rpi_bmi088_init(rpi_bmi088_t*, char const*, int, int, bmi08x_cfg const*, bmi08x_cfg const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: imu_data_reader.cpp:(.text+0x139): undefined reference to `rpi_bmi088_get_sensor_time(rpi_bmi088_t*)'
/usr/bin/ld: imu_data_reader.cpp:(.text+0x17f): undefined reference to `rpi_bmi088_get_accel(rpi_bmi088_t*, double*, double*, double*)'
/usr/bin/ld: imu_data_reader.cpp:(.text+0x1db): undefined reference to `rpi_bmi088_get_gyro(rpi_bmi088_t*, double*, double*, double*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/imu_data_reader.dir/build.make:154: imu_data_reader] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:148: CMakeFiles/imu_data_reader.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< package_name [0.42s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 0 packages finished [0.70s]
  1 package failed: package_name
  1 package had stderr output: package_name
```

I know that this error comes from not declaring dependencies or falsely compiling, so I probably messed up with the CMakeLists file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(package_name)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(ament_cmake_python REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(rclpy REQUIRED)

# include directories
include_directories(include)

# CPP Nodes:
add_executable(imu_data_reader src/imu_data_reader.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(imu_data_reader rclcpp)

# Link libraries:
add_library(rpi_bmi088 src/rpi_bmi088.c)
add_library(bmi088 src/bmi088.c)
add_library(rpi_i2c src/rpi_i2c.c)
target_link_libraries(imu_data_reader rpi_bmi088 bmi088 rpi_i2c)

install(TARGETS
  imu_data_reader
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

# Install Python modules
ament_python_install_package(${PROJECT_NAME})

# Install Python executables
install(PROGRAMS
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

ament_package()
```

My question is: how does one correctly compile header files with their corresponding .c files?

In my source files, I am including the header files `#include "package_name/rpi_bmi088.h"` where the functions are declared, but they are not being linked to the corresponding .c file in this case `src/rpi_bmi088.c` where the functions are implemented.

In case it is also important, I will include my package.xml file:

```
  ...package_info...


  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>
  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake_python</buildtool_depend>

  <depend>rclcpp</depend>
  <depend>rclpy</depend>

  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

After implementing michael's answer:

```
extern "C" 
{
    #include "package_name/rpi_bmi088.h"
}
```

I now get a different but similar error:

```
Starting >>> package_name
--- stderr: package_name                             
/usr/bin/ld: libbmi088.a(bmi088.c.o): warning: relocation against `bmi08x_config_file' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: librpi_bmi088.a(rpi_bmi088.c.o): in function `rpi_bmi088_init':
rpi_bmi088.c:(.text+0x119): undefined reference to `bmi08a_get_regs'
/usr/bin/ld: rpi_bmi088.c:(.text+0x14c): undefined reference to `bmi08g_get_regs'
/usr/bin/ld: rpi_bmi088.c:(.text+0x183): undefined reference to `bmi08a_set_power_mode'
/usr/bin/ld: rpi_bmi088.c:(.text+0x195): undefined reference to `bmi08a_set_meas_conf'
/usr/bin/ld: rpi_bmi088.c:(.text+0x1a7): undefined reference to `bmi08a_get_power_mode'
/usr/bin/ld: rpi_bmi088.c:(.text+0x200): undefined reference to `bmi08g_set_power_mode'
/usr/bin/ld: rpi_bmi088.c:(.text+0x212): undefined reference to `bmi08g_set_meas_conf'
/usr/bin/ld: librpi_bmi088.a(rpi_bmi088.c.o): in function `rpi_bmi088_get_accel':
rpi_bmi088.c:(.text+0x2a0): undefined reference to `bmi08a_get_data'
/usr/bin/ld: librpi_bmi088.a(rpi_bmi088.c.o): in function `rpi_bmi088_get_gyro':
rpi_bmi088.c:(.text+0x384): undefined reference to `bmi08g_get_data'
/usr/bin/ld: librpi_bmi088.a(rpi_bmi088.c.o): in function `rpi_bmi088_get_sensor_time':
rpi_bmi088.c:(.text+0x46e): undefined reference to `bmi08a_get_sensor_time'
/usr/bin/ld: libbmi088.a(bmi088.c.o): in function `bmi088_init':
bmi088.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `bmi08a_init'
/usr/bin/ld: bmi088.c:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `bmi08g_init'
/usr/bin/ld: libbmi088.a(bmi088.c.o): in function `bmi088_apply_config_file':
bmi088.c:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `bmi08x_config_file'
/usr/bin/ld: bmi088.c:(.text+0x76): undefined reference to `bmi08a_write_config_file'
/usr/bin/ld: libbmi088.a(bmi088.c.o): in function `bmi088_configure_data_synchronization':
bmi088.c:(.text+0x14b): undefined reference to `bmi08a_set_meas_conf'
/usr/bin/ld: bmi088.c:(.text+0x166): undefined reference to `bmi08g_set_meas_conf'
/usr/bin/ld: bmi088.c:(.text+0x1a0): undefined reference to `bmi08a_write_feature_config'
/usr/bin/ld: libbmi088.a(bmi088.c.o): in function `bmi088_configure_anymotion':
bmi088.c:(.text+0x29a): undefined reference to `bmi08a_write_feature_config'
/usr/bin/ld: libbmi088.a(bmi088.c.o): in function `bmi088_get_synchronized_data':
bmi088.c:(.text+0x32c): undefined reference to `bmi08a_get_regs'
/usr/bin/ld: bmi088.c:(.text+0x35c): undefined reference to `bmi08a_get_regs'
/usr/bin/ld: bmi088.c:(.text+0x402): undefined reference to `bmi08g_get_data'
/usr/bin/ld: libbmi088.a(bmi088.c.o): in function `bmi088_set_data_sync_int_config':
bmi088.c:(.text+0x44f): undefined reference to `bmi08a_set_int_config'
/usr/bin/ld: bmi088.c:(.text+0x475): undefined reference to `bmi08a_set_int_config'
/usr/bin/ld: bmi088.c:(.text+0x49b): undefined reference to `bmi08g_set_int_config'
/usr/bin/ld: bmi088.c:(.text+0x4c1): undefined reference to `bmi08g_set_int_config'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/imu_data_reader.dir/build.make:154: imu_data_reader] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:148: CMakeFiles/imu_data_reader.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< package_name [0.23s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 0 packages finished [0.34s]
  1 package failed: package_name
  1 package had stderr output: package_name
```

Note that:
`imu_data_reader.cpp` includes only `rpi_bmi088.h`
`rpi_bmi088.h` includes `bmi08x.h`
`rpi_bmi088.c` includes `rpi_bmi088.h`, `rpi_i2c.h` and `bmi088.h`
`bmi08x.h` includes `bmi08x_defs.h` which doesn't include anything
`rpi_i2c.c` includes `rpi_i2c.h` which doesn't include anything
`bmi088.h` also includes `bmi08x_defs.h`
`bmi088.c` includes `bmi08x.h` and `bmi088.h`

So maybe it's a dependency problem?

**UPDATE 2:**

I finally solved my problem with the following changes in the CMakeLists.txt file:

```
# Add and link libraries:

add_library(rpi_bmi088 SHARED src/rpi_bmi088.c)
add_library(bmi088 SHARED src/bmi088.c)
add_library(rpi_i2c SHARED src/rpi_i2c.c)

target_link_libraries(imu_data_reader rpi_bmi088 rpi_i2c bmi088)
```

So I was on the right track but I needed to add the SHARED keyword.

**UPDATE 3:**

Actually only 'colcon build' works but running the node I get:

```
colcon_ws/install/package_name/lib/package_name/imu_data_reader: error while loading shared libraries: librpi_bmi088.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[ros2run]: Process exited with failure 127
```

So now I'm clueless again

Comment: From the [edit message](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76210632/5): "difference between my question and the suggested duplicate is I am not trying to understand what the error means, but how to solve it in ROS2." - If you know what the error "undefined reference" means, then your first debugging steps should be answering the questions: 1. What C file **defines** the symbol, noted in the error message? 2. Is that C file compiled into the object file or library, which is passed to the linker? I see no attempts to collect that information. That is why I marked your question as the duplicate.

Comment: Note that writing "Update" section on every edit is discouraged on Stack Overflow: we expect a **question post** to contain **current** state of the problem, not a *history* of problems. In the current state of your post, which contains several error messages, it is unclear which one you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved the problem:

```
# Adding libraries:
add_library(rpi_bmi088 STATIC src/rpi_bmi088.c)
add_library(bmi088 STATIC src/bmi088.c)
add_library(rpi_i2c STATIC src/rpi_i2c.c)

# Linking libraries:
target_link_libraries(rpi_bmi088 rpi_i2c bmi088)
target_link_libraries(imu_data_reader rpi_bmi088)

# Install CPP executables:
install(TARGETS
  imu_data_reader
  rpi_bmi088
  bmi088
  rpi_i2c
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your library files are C-files and your imu_data_reader is C++. When including the headers of C files in the C++ file, I think this could fix your issue:

```
extern "C" 
{
    #include "package_name/rpi_bmi088.h"
}
```

And you might have a wrong understanding what "linking" is. Linking has not much to do with header files. Linking is (simplified) the combining of the compiled code into a single program.

Comment: This makes sense, I added it, but it didn't fix my problem.